# VBA Copy Merged Rows into single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to copy merged rows to another workbook single cell using Macro.
Does anyone knows any code snippet as reference please. Thanks.

[Source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4fqE.png)

Only tried this line here but it copies the merged rows.

```
TargetWB.Sheets("RawData").Range("C1:C" & lr3).Copy Destination:=TargetWB.Sheets("AFR").Range("C" & lastr3)
```

Comment: Maybe unmerge the cells after you copy them?

Comment: PasteSpecial >> Values

Comment: Or `TargetWB.Sheets("AFR").Range("C" & lastr3).Value = TargetWB.Sheets("RawData").Range("C1:C" & lr3).Value`

Comment: Also keep in mind that `Sheets` and `Worksheets` are very similar, but not exactly the same. It's a good habit to only use `Sheets` when you know you want that collection instead of `Worksheets`. Do not use it just because it has fewer characters or something like that.

Comment: Thanks all for you response. But should I put that line "TargetWB.Sheets("AFR").Range("C" & lastr3).Value = TargetWB.Sheets("RawData").Range("C1:C" & lr3).Value" to a loop if I have rows of merged cells?

Comment: If you try to copy the merged cells (C1:C4) which is showed on screeshot. `TargetWB.Sheets("AFR").Range("C" & lastr3).Value = TargetWB.Sheets("RawData").Range("C1").Value`

Comment: If you show more of your current code or explain your needs in a little more detail you might get more-useful approaches you can use.

Comment: Yes sorry, I updated the screenshot. basically I have a source table that has merged rows. I was trying to copy to another sheet in single cell for each. @TimWilliams the line of code you sent works but I'm just wondering if I need to do a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a loop it might look like this:

```
Sub Tester()
    Const num_cols As Long = 5
    Dim cSrc As Range, cDest As Range
    
    'set source/destination start points
    Set cSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1")
    Set cDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("A1")
    
    Do While Len(cSrc.Value) > 0 'while have data
        cDest.Resize(1, num_cols).Value = cSrc.Resize(1, num_cols).Value
        Set cSrc = cSrc.Offset(1)   'next source row
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1) 'next destination row
    Loop
End Sub
```